# How many integer solutions does $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 14$ have ?, where $x_{1} , x_{2} \geq 0$ and $x_{3} > 2$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

How many integer solutions does $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 14$ have ?, where
$x_{1} , x_{2} \geq 0$ and $x_{3} > 2$.

What should I do with this kind of problems ?. Thanks.

Comment: Imagine you are distributing 14 apples to 3 people. Since the third person needs to receive at least 3 apples, give him 3 apples, and then count the number of distributions of 11 apples to 3 people. This is a standard stars and bars problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Answer (score 2):

Throw three balls away to give them to $x_3$ , i.e., so that $x_3>2$ , and then apply a stars-and-bars to $x_1+x_2+x_3=12$. Stars and bars gives you the number of nonnegative solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=k$